# HazelCast .NET - Clear Maps dynamically

Tags: c#, .net-core, hazelcast, hazelcast-imap

I'm creating several maps to cache some info for my application.
When some events are triggered I want to clear those caches.
I have a list of all maps names I should clear but I couldn't find a way to dynamically get those maps in order to clear them. Basically I have:

```
var mapsNames = ["map-1", "map-2", "map-3"];
```

And I want a simple way of doing things like:

```
var client = HazelcastClient.NewHazelcastClient();
foreach (var name in mapsNames)
{
    var map = client.GetMap(name);
    map.Clear();
}
```

In the [README.md](https://github.com/hazelcast/hazelcast-csharp-client) we do have some examples like:

```
var client = HazelcastClient.NewHazelcastClient();

var personnelMap = client.GetMap("personnelMap");
personnelMap.Put("Alice", "IT");
personnelMap.Put("Bob", "IT");
personnelMap.Put("Clark", "IT");
Console.WriteLine("Added IT personnel. Logging all known personnel");
foreach(var entry in personnelMap.entrySet())
{
    Console.WriteLine("{0} is in {1} department", entry.Key, entry.Value );
}
client.Shutdown();
```

That indicates we should have a method `GetMap` that is non-generic but I couldn't find it. The only one avaiable is `GetMap<TKey, TValue>`. Are the docs wrong? Is there a way to get a Map by its name without using some ugly reflection?

Thanks in advance,

Answer (score 0):

Did you try (`ICollection<IDistributedObject> GetDistributedObjects()`) https://github.com/hazelcast/hazelcast-csharp-client/blob/v3.12.1/Hazelcast.Net/Hazelcast.Client/HazelcastClient.cs#L230 ?

You can iterate through all the existing maps, and you can use https://github.com/hazelcast/hazelcast-csharp-client/blob/v3.12.1/Hazelcast.Net/Hazelcast.Core/IDistributedObject.cs#L53 to check is the distributed object is of type map service.